# QuickBlox Access direct URL of image stored in public blob — Android Content Module

Tags: quickblox

I have retrieved the Users Blob id. How do I get the public URL for that blob?
 blob= user.getFileId()

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve file url only if you have blob, not just blob id

Download blob by id:

```
QBContent.getFile(20223, new QBCallbackImpl() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            QBFileResult fileResult = (QBFileResult) result;
            QBFile file = fileResult.getFile();
            String fileURL = file.getPublicUrl();
        } 
    }
});
```

**Note:**
To get direct access to file you have to upload it with public=true

```
Boolean fileIsPublic = true;
QBContent.uploadFileTask(file1, fileIsPublic, new QBCallbackImpl() { ...
```

Comment: Thanks..Let me have a go at it

Comment: When using getFile().. can i access the file of other user..? Am trying to load other all users avatars by retrieving public Url using each user blobid by its throwing a null pointer..

Comment: Tried the getFile() function and its throwing a null pointer exception? Any idea why?

Comment: Which line? please provide log

Comment: Am getting the users info, login and blobid, at the same instance using the blodid in the getfile() so as to get the url,so as to store the users details either in sqlite or coustom object, but when I include the getFile() application is throwing a null pointer

Comment: Am creating a function where am passing the Blobid so a to retrieve the public url

Comment: and crash log as well

Comment: for (QBUser user : ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getAllQbUsers()) {
    Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    userMap.put(KEY_USER_LOGIN, user.getLogin());
    userMap.put(KEY_USER_BLOB, user.getFileId() + "");
    userMap.put(KEY_USER_URL,getUrl(user.getFileId()));
    //Log.d("URL", getUrl(user.getFileId())) ;
    usersListForAdapter.add(userMap);
   }

Comment: public String getUrl(int blobId) {
  QBContent.getFile(blobId, new QBCallbackImpl() {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(Result result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
     QBFileResult fileResult = (QBFileResult) result;
     QBFile file = fileResult.getFile();
     String fileURL = file.getPublicUrl().toString();
     url = fileURL.toString();
    }
   }
  });
  return url;
 }